# get document fields data type with firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

I would like to get a document from  firebase and find out the document fields type.
for example field Name datatype String, field Age datatype int

How can I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check each variable type as follow:

```
print(foo.runtimeType);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific: what is foo? (I have the DocumentSnapshot object)

Comment: @AsiB replace foo with your data. Get the data from the snapshot and put each one in the print statement.